# Should a fourier saw wave function return values greater than 1?

Tags: fourier-series

For a sine function, the maximum value `sin(x)` returns will always be 1 (and -1) correct?
Is this the same for a Fourier function?

I'm writing a program that simulatates oscillators, and my fourier functions are  returning slightly more than one at the tips of the saw wave, and it's a bit unsettling.
If it is normal, then I can move on with things, but if it's not - then I'll have to investigate whatever programming issue it is.

If you're interested, here's a paste of the code [pseudo code](http://pastebin.com/ztHJ5Bej) and  [original c](http://pastebin.com/rvuP2tSU) .

If it *is* normal - any interesting implications for it? 
For me - this program is a step towards generating sound with it - a value of more than 1 would cause clipping (ie you'd simply be chopping those tips off), so perhaps some gain reduction is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal. The Fourier series of discontinuous functions always show a similar pattern. It's called Gibbs' phenomenon (see for example [Wikipedia: Gibbs phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon))